# Rails + PostgreSQL: How to get products that have been ordered at least once + get the order # and the manager id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have these models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product
end
```

I want to get a list of all products which have been ordered at least once along with the timestamp of when the order has been made (`orders.created_at`) and the code of the order (`orders.no`) and the admin who processed the orderd (`orders.processed_by_admin_id`). And finally, I would want to list the output by `orders.created_at`.

After some googling, I was able to come up with something like this:

```
Product.joins(:orders)
       .group("(products.id) having count(products.id) > 0")
       .select("products.*", "max(orders.created_at) as last_order_time")
       .sort_by(&:last_order_time).reverse
```

This gets me the list of products ordered at least once, sorted out by the timestamp. However, I got stucked here being unable to fetch yet the `orders.no` and `orders.processed_by_admin_id`. I am not sure if the procedure I follow is the right one.

The desired output is something like:

```
products.* | last_order_time | order_no | order_processed_by_admin_id
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I've tried many times to get similar effect but always failed. It seams that making SQL query by ActiveRecord for model Product you can only get in result fields defined by schema for that model. As I never needed those data in production when needed I was simply adding `as` to query to cheat ActiveRecord. so ex. `.select("products.id", "max(orders.created_at) as products.field_you dont_need", "orders.no", "orders.processed_by_admin_id")` I was hoping that you can achieve it by some `attr_reader` but unfortunatelly no. So more than helping i'm waiting curious for an answer

Comment: Of course you can get it by raw query like `Product.connection.select_all('sql')` but it will not give objects, just simple records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get a list of all products which have been ordered at least once along with the timestamp of when the order has been made (orders.created_at) and the code of the order (orders.no) and the admin who processed the orderd (orders.processed_by_admin_id). And finally, I would want to list the output by orders.created_at.

When writing a complicated query, I like to write the plain SQL first.

Let's start with a query to get the most recent order for each product.

```sql
select product_id, id, 
  row_number() over ( 
    partition by product_id order by created_at 
  ) as recency_ranking 
from orders
;
```

This is called a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/interactive/tutorial-window.html). For each product, the most recent order will have a `recency_ranking` of 1. Now we can join this query to our `products` table.

```sql
select p.*,
  x.id as order_id,
  x.no as order_number,
  x.order_processed_by_admin_id,
  x.created_at as order_created_at
from products p
inner join (
  select product_id, 
    id, 
    created_at, 
    row_number() over ( 
      partition by product_id order by created_at 
    ) as recency_ranking,
    no,
    order_processed_by_admin_id 
  from orders
) x
  on x.product_id = p.id
    and x.recency_ranking = 1
order by x.created_at
;
```

When we join another query like this it's called a **subquery**. Note how we join `on recency_ranking = 1`.

To run this whole query in ActiveRecord, I'd suggest `find_by_sql`:

```rb
products = Product.find_by_sql('select p.*, x.id ...')
products.first.order_created_at #=> '2019-01-01 ...'
```

Comment: Thank you, @JaredBeck, great answer and really does solve my problem! Just wondering about the `order_processed_by_admin_id ` - in the `Order` model, it has this association that it belongs to the `Admin` model. However, when I try something like this: `products.first.order_processed_by_admin.full_name`, I get this error message: `undefined method 'admin' for #<Product:0x007fb1aa1381f8>`. It looks like the association is broken?

Comment: Re: "undefined method 'admin' for Product", it is Order that has this association, not Product, right? So, the error message is correct and expected. Instead, use `product.order.admin` (inefficient) or join the `admins` table to the big query.

Comment: just wondering - how do I also include there the total count of **products**? I tried it like this: `select p.*,
  x.id as order_id,
  x.no as order_number,
  x.order_processed_by_admin_id,
  x.created_at as order_created_at, COUNT(x.id) as total_orders ...`, but it gives me always `1`. Plan **B** would be to fetch the count in Rails, but having it in the query would more efficient